A toy example of a hom functor
I'd like to check my intuition for a hom functor with a following toy example.
Let $\mathbf C$ be a category with three object $A$, $B$ and $C$ and morphisms $f: A \rightarrow B$, $g: A \rightarrow B$, $h: B \rightarrow C$, $k: A \rightarrow C$.
Am I right that $\mathrm{Hom}(A, -)$ maps objects as
$\mathrm{Hom}(A, A) = \{id_A\}$,
$\mathrm{Hom}(A, B) = \{f, g\}$, and
$\mathrm{Hom}(A, C) = \{h\circ f, h\circ g, k\}$,
and maps morphisms as
$\mathrm{Hom}(A, f) = \{f\}$,
$\mathrm{Hom}(A, g) = \{g\}$,
$\mathrm{Hom}(A, h) = \{h\circ f, h\circ g\}$, and
$\mathrm{Hom}(A, k) = \{k\}$

Please indicate why you are unsure.

I'm unsure if I correctly determined $Hom(A, -)$ on morphisms $f$, $g$, $h$ and $k$.

That doesn't type-check. $\mathrm{Hom}(A, f)$ is not a set, it's a function.

@NaïmFavier Isn't $Hom(A, f)$ form a set of functions?

No, it's a function from $\mathrm{Hom}(A, A)$ to $\mathrm{Hom}(A, B)$. You should check the definition of a functor.

@NaïmFavier So, following the example $\mathrm{Hom}(A, f): {id_A} \rightarrow  {f, g}$, is it correct?

That's the type, yes. Now you must say what the function does.

Your example is about right but I would clarify that the mapping of morphisms by the $Hom(A,-)$ functor, is a morphism. Let $f,g,h,k$ be as you defined. Then,
$Hom(A,f): Hom(A,A) \rightarrow Hom(A,B)$ is defined by $id_A \rightarrow f\circ id_A=f$. Following the same reasoning, it follows for example that $Hom(A,h): Hom(A,B) \rightarrow Hom(A,C)$ maps $f$ to $h\circ f$ and $g$ to $h\circ g$

I guess ${id_A}$ must be by default since every object has an identity arrow. And I didn't get why $h \in \mathrm{Hom}(A, A)$. The only morphism in  $\mathrm{Hom}(A, A)$ is ${id_A}$. Correct me if I'm wrong.

@IgorWolkov marta unfortunately seems quite confused; you're on the right page with everything you say.

You're absolutely right, the only  morphism is the identity. I'm editing my answer. I think the example you provided in the question is about right but I would write the morphisms more clearly.
